# IVR integration with dynamic recording definition and callback invocation after users proof

Tags: asterisk, telephony, ivr, pbx

I need to integrate my website with some IVR system in order to achieve the folowing: when user inputs some data into a form and presses submit button -> his imput is sending to the IVR, the call starts and the message of IVR contains data which was input. System asks user to proff/dismiss it. -> if he approves - http request is made by IVR, the url should contain params with values based on user's imput. 
Is it possible? Which systems support it?

Comment: Your question isn't terribly clear, so before I can answer you, I have a question:  is your user on a phone, or a website?  You say IVR (phone), but then talk about them pressing a submit button (website).  What are you trying to do?

Comment: At a web site, after user will input data and press a button, I want to send data to (as far as I understand) some pbx like asterix e.t.c. and then to make a call there. IVR should be defined based on users input

Comment: I found that Twilio solves most of this issues like calling from the browser:

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/client/hello-monkey

Comment: passing data for initiating IVR : https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml

Comment: performing actions when user submits during a call: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action

Comment: but what is un acceptable for me is that it is unable to use it on ios safary without involving platform components usage. Maybe somebody knows some alternative?